# Is there a way to deploy all apks from a multi module maven project?

Tags: android-maven-plugin

I'm trying to create a multi module maven project from several inter-dependent android projects.

I've created individual pom files under the module folders and created a pom.xml in the parent folder. I've added all the modules to the parent pom.xml.

Now, when I do "mvn install" from parent folder, all the modules get compiled, apks are generated and the apks from modules that have tests are deployed to the virtual devices and instrumentation tests are run. All of this happens as expected.

Now, if I just want to deploy all the apks from the multi module project to all active virtual devices, how would I go about doing that? Doing "mvn android:deploy" from parent folder does not deploy any apks. It says "finished" for the parent project and then all other submodules are skipped. But no apks are deployed.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Also, on a related note, "mvn install" bails out when one of the instrumentation tests fails. Is there a way to get "mvn install" to build other modules even when one of the instrumentation tests from previous modules failed?

Thank you,

Comment: You would have to actively go into the folders that are actually apk projects and run android:deploy there. It might be possible to change the android maven plugin to skip non apk projects and run deploy in the rest of them. You could try to provide a pull request that allows that.. I can pull it in ;-)